# How to Require Confirmation on Form Close When there is Changed Data in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have simple `Form1` with `datagridview`  and I've enabled editing and adding.

Now, when I click on closing form button, and if some of existing cell values are changed or new row has been added I want dialogue box to open (for example, asking me if I want to save changes or don't), and if there is no changes , just to perform simple form closing.

How can I accomplish this ?

Ok, here is what I've got so far.
I'm trying to this one using CSLA framework, I've created root editable collection `public class PDVCollection : BusinessBindingListBase<PDVCollection, PDV>` and editable child `public class PDV : BusinessBase<PDV>`
On Form1 I've got this code

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    public PDVCollection s;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.DataSource = PDVCollection.GetAll();

    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = (PDVCollection)bindingSource1.DataSource;

        s = s.Save();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = s;


    }



    private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex > -1)
        {

            PDV sel = (PDV)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

            s = (PDVCollection)bindingSource1.DataSource;
            s.Remove(sel);
            s = s.Save();
        }

    }
```

i want to cut `s = s.Save();` from both `toolStripButton1_Click` and `toolStripButton3_Click` and If something is changed/added/deleted and I perform closing event

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (//some code to implement)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                s = (PDVCollection)bindingSource1.DataSource;
                s = s.Save();
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your title was horrible. It said nothing about your question. Also, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: have a bool variable.. let's say, bool valueChanged. Set it to true when there is a change. And, before form close event, check for the variable and show the confirmation message.

Comment: Is the DGV data-bound?

Comment: Yes, I used bindingsource to bound dgv to collection of objects

Comment: For your solution you need save original datasource against which you can compare data of `DataGridView`. Boolean flag will not effective, because of scenario where some value was changed first, then was changed back to original before closing form

Comment: In your case, I think, better approach will be create two buttons `Save` and `Cancel`. `Save` button will save data without checking of changes and close form(Or you can check for changes on database level and update/insert only changed/added valued). And `Cancel` button will cancel all changes and close form

Comment: I've already have 2 buttons, save which will perform adding and updating object, and delete.I'm using csla , and what I want is if user forgot to click on button save the form will inform him if he made some changes and if he wants to save them.

Comment: Use `BindingSource.ListChanged` to set a dirty flag!

Comment: I edited my answer below to include this, but if you're using CSLA, there's an IsDirty flag on each business object. Just iterate over the business objects in the data source and check the IsDirty flag on each in the FormClosed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing databinding to a DataSource, then you can use the datasource to determine whether it has been changed in the FormClosing or FormClosed event.  The actual implementation would be up to the type of datasource you are using.

If you're not specifying a datasource, then the data by default can be accessed in the Rows collection of the DataGrid. That collection class doesn't have a "changed" flag by default, but it DOES have a CollectionChanged event that you could hook up.

So, in your form's construtor, you could do a

DataGrid1.CollectionChanged += Rows_CollectionChanged;

And then in your Rows_CollectionChanged you could set a flag that data has changed and needs to be saved.  Obviously giving much more detail would require knowing more about the details of your datagrid and datasource.

Per the comments below, you may want more than a flag depending on how you define "changed".  If you need to know that a field was changed, then changed back to the original value then as a commenter below says a simple flag wouldn't do it, and you might need to store a shadow copy of the original data.

That said, if you need to handle really complicated undo scenarios you're going to want datasource designed for that, which is a whole different topic.

EDIT:  If you're using CSLA objects as your data source, then there should be an IsDirty flag on the objects.  So just iterate over the items in the datasource on the FormClosed event and check the IsDirty flag for each object.

Comment: If value was changed to new value and later will be changed back to the original value. Then flag value will be `true` even actually no changes happened

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **flag** variable and initially set it to **false**

```
 bool isAnythingChange = false;
```

And make this variable to true on new row add, or value change event. For sample I have shown below

```
 void txt_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      isAnythingChange = true;
 }
```

And while you are handling form closing event make point to check **isAnythingChange**. If it's value is true then ask for confirmation or else close form without confirmation.

EDIT:
As you maintain in your question, updated code may be like this.

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isAnythingChange)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                s = (PDVCollection)bindingSource1.DataSource;
                s = s.Save();
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one will resolve only one part of my problem , what if I change value and then change it back to original value, isAnythingChange will still be true.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is final working solution, if anyone is looking for it.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    public PDVCollection s;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.DataSource = PDVCollection.GetAll();
        s = (StopaPDVCollection)bindingSource1.DataSource;
    }


    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        s = s.Save();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = s;


    }


    private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex > -1)
        {

            PDV sel = (PDV)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

            s.Remove(sel);

        }

    }



    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (s.IsDirty)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes", "Message", "Poruka", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                s = (PDVCollection)bindingSource1.DataSource;

                s = s.Save();
                bindingSource1.DataSource = s;
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }

    }

}
```